# Где в предложении грамматическая ошибка?

Tags: грамматика

Где в предложении грамматическая ошибка:

> "У Аси чёрные волосы, остриженные и
> причёсанные, как у мальчика."

Учительница в предложении зачеркнула все запятые, а в слове *причёсанные* букву *е*! Я понимаю, что "как у мальчика" может быть зависимым от причастия причёсанные. Но разве  "как у мальчика" не может быть сравнительным оборотом?

Comment: Дима, хотите заранее заручиться поддержкой из интернета? Проще и скромнее обратиться к учительнице и попросить ее объяснить эти правки.

Comment: Варяг-91,я учусь на дом.обучении,учит-ца не учит меня писать сочинения,этим занимается моя мама.Я считаю,что педагог слишком придирается.Она иногда бывает неправа,например ,я задавал вопрос здесь о приложениях ,она нам с мамой ответила,что согласованных приложений не существует.Учитель должен знать полностью программу.Я сомневаюсь в её компетентности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может.

Вообще-то "как у мальчика" волосы острижены, а причёсываем мы все одинаково. Но это смысл, а с грамматикой всё в порядке, с пунктуацией тоже. Может, учительница хотела сказать, что "причёсаны как у мальчика" - фразеологизм, но это скорее к "острижены как у мальчика = под мальчика". Но здесь есть и прямое сравнение со стрижкой мальчика, запятая возможна. Лучше избегать таких выражений, заменить более точным и ясным выражением: У Аси чёрные волосы и стрижка "под мальчика". Или: У Аси короткие чёрные волосы, что делает её похожей на мальчика.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы исправила предложения таким образом: У Аси чёрные волосы, коротко остриженные (или "короткая стрижка"), как у мальчика".

Ошибка в том, что при обособлении оборота в предложенном варианте можно подумать, что стригутся и причесываются только мальчики. А вот короткая стрижка характерна  для мальчиков.

И прически бывают "под мальчика", но тогда сравнительный оборот не обособляется: У Аси чёрные волосы, прическа как у мальчика".

Answer (score 0):

Если убрать лишние слова, то фраза будет выглядеть так: У Аси волосы остриженные и причесанные (характеристика волос), как у мальчика (сравнение).

Comment: "Причесанные" не на месте (девочки тоже причесываются), можно только "прическа как у мальчика". Это тот же сравнительный оборот, но только в роли необособленного определения, а не попутного сравнения.