# Двоеточие перед подлинным выражением, которое включено в авторское предложение в качестве его члена

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

Мой вопрос адресован всем, но в особенности тем, кто редактирует вопросы, задаваемые на этом сайте. Часто встречаются заголовки такого формата:

> Почему то-то и так-то в предложении: "Мое предложение"?

Не все ставят двоеточие после слова *предложение*.

У Розенталя [находим](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/46411/%D0%93%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D1%80%25):

> Примечание. Подлинные выражения (цитаты), вставленные в текст в качестве элементов предложения, выделяются кавычками, но двоеточие перед ними не ставится:
>
> Это «не хочу» поразило Антона Прокофьевича (Г.); Предположение дневального, что «взводный нажрался и дрыхнет где-то в избе», всё больше собирало сторонников (Ф.); Он вспомнил пословицу «За двумя зайцами погонишься — ни одного не поймаешь» и отказался от первоначального плана; С криком «Спасайте детей!» юноша бросился в горящее здание.
>
> Но если перед подлинным выражением имеются слова **предложение**, выражение, надпись и т. п., то перед ними ставится двоеточие:
>
> Над воротами возвысилась вывеска, изображающая дородного амура с опрокинутым факелом в руке, с подписью: «Здесь продаются и обиваются гробы простые и крашеные…» (П.); Мимо станции проносились скорые поезда с табличками на вагонах: «Москва — Владивосток»; Разберите предложение: «Сверкнула молния, и грянул гром».

Похоже, не все согласны с подобным особым подходом к словам предложение, выражение, надпись и т. п.

Лопатин это слова [не упоминает](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137):

> г) если прямая речь непосредственно включается в авторское предложение в качестве его члена, то она заключается в кавычки, знаки же препинания ставятся по условиям авторского предложения: Сказав Гричмару фразу «Легкой жизни не бывает, есть лишь легкая смерть», Крымов поймал на себе беспокойный, предупреждающий взгляд Стишова (Бонд.).

В связи этим у меня два вопроса:

1. Не устарел ли особый подходом (по Розенталю) к словам *предложение*, *выражение*, *надпись* и т. п.? Насколько он обязателен в наше время?
2. Какую модель нам выбрать для оформления вопросов на нашем сайте?

Answer (score 1):

Понимание фразы как ***предложения*** требует начальной прописной и определяет постановку двоеточия. И напротив, — далее излагаю частный взгляд, — отношение к фразе (цитате), как к ***фразе***, т. е. обороту или выражению, освобождает от необходимости ставить двоеточие и прописную после кавычек:

> ... он вспомнил пословицу «за двумя зайцами погонишься — ни одного не
>   поймаешь» и отказался от первоначального плана...

По теме же выбора модели оформления: есть возможность, которая вполне реализуется в рамках  текстового редактора через опцию «Цитата». Исключение пары кавычек фоновым выделением — удачное решение и хорошее подспорье, заслуживающее более частого применения.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Применительно к заголовкам вопросов изменение фона и другие опции текстового редактора не реализованы, насколько я знаю. Если я не прав, подскажите, какие возможности есть для редактирования заголовков на этом сайте.

Comment: Да, и как для комментариев, тоже. Однако ж, заголовок — всегда отдельная статья, где важно не многословие, а сжатость предельная. Редактор тут может помочь только «встроенный».